# How to fix 'The entity type requires a primary key to be defined.' error in ASP.Net Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm setting up a new database using the code-first method. And after i defined my models with their key attributes, It still can't manage to find the primary key for the models.

I have tried using the traditional 'Id' naming and the [Key] attributes.

One of my models is this one.

```
public class Band
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id;
    public Institution Institution;
    public BandName BandName;
}
```

And the code for the context is

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Band> bands { get; set; }
}
```

```
PM> add-migration migration_1
Output: The entity type 'Band' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add getter and setter to your Id.

Your class should look like this :

```
public class Band
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public Institution Institution { get; set; }
    public BandName BandName { get; set; }
}
```

EF core need to have a setter to when it reads data from database and populate your dataset. 
Think also to add getters and setters for the other class properties (as I added it in your example).

NB: A private setter will also work `public long Id { get; private set; }`